# Bootstrap CSS strange conflict with qtip2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, qtip, qtip2

I have a very strange bug when using Bootstrap css with qtip2:

I have a button, on which i bind a qtip popup:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deleteButton">
    Delete
</button>
```

I bind the qtip like this (is working fine)

```
var $button = $("#deleteButton");
$button.qtip({
    show: {
        event: 'mouseenter',
        solo: true,
        effect: false,
        delay: 100
    },
    content: function (event, api) {
         return "Tooltip message";   
    }
});
```

As soon as the button gets the css class `disabled` (only the class, not the attribute), the qtip stops working.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdJ68/6/)

**Important:**
If the button doesn't have the class `btn`, even having the `disabled` class, the qtip still works. So the issue has something to do with the `Bootstrap` `btn` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap.min.css find

```
.btn.disabled, .btn[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .btn {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .65;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

and delete pointer-events: none;

or just overwrite the bootstrap style like this
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KX9L2/1/)

Comment: Works great. I didn't knew about this property in css